# FB like URL Creation with .htaccess File and PHP

Tags: php, html

Let website link is www.abc.com
I have 3 PHP Files.

1. index.php
2. profile.php
3. add.php

I want to convert

1. index.php url like "www.abc.com/home"
2. profile.php url (before - "www.abc.com/profile.php?id=no1") to "www.abc.com/user_name"
   (or "www.abc.com/abrar" or "www.abc.com/jahin" or "www.abc.com/piash" like this)
3. add.php url like "www.abc.com/add"

I am using RAW PHP.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to have my profile like

" https://www.facebook.com/saniabinta "

another page like
" https://www.facebook.com/add/341677349195065/ "

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `.htaccess` file by `rewriteRule`. Example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^home$ ./home.php
RewriteRule ^user_name/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^add$ ./add.php
```

Comment: I want to have my profile like

https://www.facebook.com/saniabinta

another page like
https://www.facebook.com/add/341677349195065/

Is it possible?